# Animating in float layout KIVY

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am new to python and kivy.  I am trying a small game, I got struck in the starting itself, I want to use float layout, and make widgets fall from top to bottom in it.  The widgets size is (0.1,0.1), the animation of movement would take pixes as option, how can I know the max limits of x and y corner pixels in the layout, I tried to know the pixels count of float layout by using the dp(value) from Module: kivy.metrics, however it is showing only as 0,0.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.metrics import dp

class Test(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print(dp(self.size))


class game(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game().run()
```

Code is just an example on how I tried to get dp. How can I move a widget without knowing the max pixels possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `Widget.size` of a layout widget seems to be (1, 1) when initialized, if you don't specify it manually, but at the widget creation time (i.e. the `Widget.__init__`) you cannot get any other size value from it.

After the widget is created and returned from the `App.build` method it automatically gets added to the widget tree of the application as a root widget right under the window.

When widget gets added to a parent it also gets resized according to it's size hint value relative to it's parent size. The default `Widget.size_hint` value is also (1, 1), which makes it scale to the parent size, the window size in this case.

Only after this happens can you get the final size of the widget, e.g. in the `App.on_start` method that gets called after the `App.build`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class Test(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print(self.parent)
        # None
        print(self.get_parent_window())
        # None
        print(self.get_root_window())
        # None
        print(self.size)
        # [1, 1]
        print(self.size_hint)
        # [1, 1]

class game(App):
    def build(self):
        print(self.root)
        # None
        return Test()

    def on_start(self):
        print(self.root)
        # <__main__.Test object at 0x10a9d8a10>
        print(self.root.parent)
        # <kivy.core.window.window_pygame.WindowPygame object at 0x10a90d6d0>
        print(self.root.get_parent_window())
        # <kivy.core.window.window_pygame.WindowPygame object at 0x10a90d6d0>
        print(self.root.get_root_window())
        # <kivy.core.window.window_pygame.WindowPygame object at 0x10a90d6d0>
        print(self.root.size)
        # [800, 600]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game().run()
```

All of the application and widget lifecycle and behavior is described in the Kivy docs, but it's rather spread all over the place between guides and API reference. Definitely don't miss out the [Widget Programming Guide](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/widgets.html).

Comment: With your code I can find the size of the window, but not the widget, if I keep widget size as (0.5,0.5), then i can't know the actual size for moving the widgets. Is there a way to over come this. Please bare with me, I am from VB.net WPF, so python & kivy both are new to me, but learning as much fast as I can.

Comment: @surpavan The size `[800, 600]` is the actual final size of the `Test` widget after it got resized to parent window size automatically. If you set `Test` widget size hint to (0.5, 0.5) in the example, it'll only get resized to half the window size and you'll get `[400.0, 300.0]` on the output.

Comment: Got it, however, if it gets resized every time, how can I program animations based on px. And more over, at initiation the px values are different from the ones after start.  And I think if there is a better article on Layout vs Widget sizes and positions would be goo, kivy documentation is clear but not explanatory. Thank you.

Comment: Any other way to know it, else any method through which I can move widgets.

Comment: I want to run some code on my widget as soons as it knows who's his parent. What function in the Widget LifeCycle should I use? I don't want to use a method outside of my widget class, so the on_start on the App class wouldn't do it..